# VSCode tasks.json: Could not find the preLaunchTask

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a multiroot project: a React client and a TypeScript Express server as follows:

```
.vscode
    launch.json
    tasks.json
client
    src
    package.json
    ...
server
    dist
    src
        server.ts
    package.json
    tsconfig.json
    webpack.config.js
    yarn.lock
```

launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Server",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server/src/server.ts",
      "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/server/dist/**/*.js"
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "build",
      "sourceMaps": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Tasks.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "npm",
      "identifier": "build",
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "path": "${workspaceFolder}/server"
    }
  ]
}
```

This same configuration works in another project where the package.json is in the `workspaceFolder`. I thought `path` would work, but I get `Could not find the preLaunchTask 'build'`.

Obviously in my `server/package.json`, I have the following:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "yarn clean && webpack",
  ...
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy the .vscode folder to the server subfolder:

```
...
client
  ...
server
  .vscode
    launch.json
    tasks.json
  ...
```